# Meaning of と together with トラブルになる

Tags: grammar, particle-と, reading-comprehension

> いじめの問題が起こったとき、学校が最初に調査をすると法律で決まっています。しかし、学校が調査をするとき、子どもの親など**と**トラブルになることが増えています。裁判になったことも５年で２０件以上ありました。
>   When the problem of bullying occurs the law says that the school will investigate from the outset. However, when a school investigates, *the number of incidents where* the children's parents *become troubled* is increasing. There has also been over 20 裁判になったこと in *the last* 5 years.

I'm not familiar with the word トラブル. Does トラブルになる mean "become inconvenienced" or does it mean "get into trouble" i.e. displease someone?

I can't understand what the と in 子どもの親などと is doing. I think I must be completely misunderstanding 子どもの親などとトラブルになること.

I'm guessing that 裁判になったこと (literally "thing that became a judgment") means 'prosecutions'. Is this a set phrase? Have I misunderstood?

Comment: I think "子供の親など"  includes people other than parents such as sports coach school employed and so on. And I was wondering if ５年で is in the last 5 years. I thought 5 years that they had surveyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とトラブルになる means "get into trouble with", so 子どもの親などとトラブルになること means "to get into trouble with parents of children".

裁判になる means "to be put on trial". It means 'prosecutions' as you said.

If the subjects are added, it would be easy to understand. It is しかし、学校が調査をするとき、(学校が)子どもの親などとトラブルになることが増えています。(そのトラブルが)裁判になったことも５年で２０件以上ありました。

I am translated this sentence as "However, when a school investigates, the number of troubles between schools and parents of children are increasing. The number of  the troubles which was put on trial was over 20 in the last 5 years."

Comment: I see. The school gets into trouble **with** the parents. i.e. the parents take the school to court. That makes sense.